# d3js error while drawing the chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I tried to parse the timeStamp from a dataset for my chart. It says

"Uncaught TypeError: t.slice is not a function" when I was trying to parse my dataset.

this is the way I tried it,

```js
var jsonDataLoadAvg;
var jsonDataFlightRequest;
var jsonDataMemoryAvg;
var DURATION = 100;


//onclick function which will trigger the option for 30mints,1 hour etc
function DurationOnClick(element) {

    var buttonId = element.id;
    var buttonName = $(element).attr("name");
    var chartType = $('#chartType').val();
    var idValue = $('#IdValue').val();

    //here the spinner will indicate untill the data loads to the map
    if ('InFlight' != buttonName) {

        if ('LoadAverage' == buttonName) {
            $('#container2').empty();
            $('#container2').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-4x"></i>');

        } else {

            $('#container1').empty();
            $('#container1').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-4x"></i>');

        }
    } else {
        $('#container3').empty();
        $('#container3').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-4x"></i>');

    }

    //after user click the option here we are changing the option black to red.
    $(element).button('toggle');

    restCaller(buttonName, idValue, chartType, buttonId);

}

//ajax call to the UI back end get the data to the charts 
function restCaller(buttonName, idValue, chartType, buttonId) {

    var html1 = '<svg id="lineChartSVGchart1" class="lineChart--svg"> <defs> ' +
        '<linearGradient id="lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">' +
        ' <stop class="lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea--top" offset="0%" /> <stop class="lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea--bottom" offset="100%" /> ' +
        '</linearGradient> </defs> </svg>';
    var html2 = '<svg id="lineChartSVGchart2" class="lineChart--svg"> <defs>' +
        ' <linearGradient id="lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">' +
        ' <stop class="lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea--top" offset="0%" /> <stop class="lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea--bottom" offset="100%" />' +
        ' </linearGradient> </defs> </svg>';
    var html3 = '<svg id="lineChartSVGchart3" class="lineChart--svg"> <defs>' +
        ' <linearGradient id="lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1"> ' +
        '<stop class="lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea--top" offset="0%" /> <stop class="lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea--bottom" offset="100%" />' +
        ' </linearGradient> </defs> </svg>';

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: caramel.context + "/controllers/healthStatistics/healthStatistics_getrequest.jag",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {"formtype": buttonName, "idValue": idValue, "chartType": chartType, "duration": buttonId},
        success: function (data) {

            if ('error' != data.status) {

                if ('InFlight' == buttonName) {

                    $('#lineChartSVGchart3').empty();
                    $('#container3').empty();
                    $('#container3').append(html3);
                    jsonDataFlightRequest = data;
                    generalChart('chart3', jsonDataFlightRequest, buttonName);


                }
                else if ('LoadAverage' == buttonName) {

                    $('#lineChartSVGchart2').empty();
                    $('#container2').empty();
                    $('#container2').append(html2);
                    jsonDataLoadAvg = data;
                    generalChart('chart2', jsonDataLoadAvg, buttonName);

                }
                else {

                    $('#lineChartSVGchart1').empty();
                    $('#container1').empty();
                    $('#container1').append(html1);
                    jsonDataMemoryAvg = data;
                    generalChart('chart1', jsonDataMemoryAvg, buttonName);

                }

            } else {

                //print error message in any case.
                var n = noty({text: data.message, layout: 'bottomRight', type: 'error'});
            }

        }

    }).always(function () {
    });

}

//body onload function will trigger when the page loads
function bodyOnLoad() {

    var buttonNames;
    var chartType = $('#chartType').val();
    if ("Cluster" != chartType) {

        buttonNames = ["LoadAverage", "MemoryConsumption"];

    } else {

        buttonNames = ["InFlight", "LoadAverage", "MemoryConsumption"];
    }

    buttonNames.forEach(function (entry) {
        initialLoad(entry, chartType);

    });

}

//initialy acalling to the REST API and get data for the chart
function initialLoad(buttonName, chartType) {

    var idValue = $('#IdValue').val();
    var buttonId = "1Hour";
    restCaller(buttonName, idValue, chartType, buttonId);

}


function generalChart(chart, dataset, buttonName) {

    var elementId = chart;
    var dataChart;
    var drawchart;

    if ('InFlight' != buttonName) {

        if ('LoadAverage' == buttonName) {
            dataChart = "data.memberAverageLoadAverage";
            drawchart = "d.memberAverageLoadAverage";

        } else {
            dataChart = "data.memberAverageMemoryConsumption";
            drawchart = "d.memberAverageMemoryConsumption";

        }
    } else {
        dataChart = "data.inFlightRequestCount";
        drawchart = "d.inFlightRequestCount";

    }
    function drawLineChart(elementId, data) {


        // data manipulation first
        data.forEach(function (data) {
            data.timeStamp = new Date(data.timeStamp);
        });

        // TODO code duplication check how you can avoid that
        var containerEl = document.getElementById(elementId),
            width = containerEl.clientWidth,
            height = width * 0.4,
            margin = {
                top: 30,
                right: 10,
                left: 10
            },

            detailWidth = 98,
            detailHeight = 55,
            detailMargin = 10,

            container = d3.select(containerEl),
            svg = container.select('svg')
                .attr('width', width)
                .attr('height', height + margin.top),

            x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width - detailWidth]),
            xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
                .ticks(8)
                .tickSize(-height),
            xAxisTicks = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
                .ticks(16)
                .tickSize(-height)
                .tickFormat(''),
            y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
            yAxisTicks = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
                .ticks(12)
                .tickSize(width)
                .tickFormat('')
                .orient('right'),

            area = d3.svg.area()
                .interpolate('linear')
                .x(function (d) {
                    return x(d.timeStamp) + detailWidth / 2;
                })
                .y0(height)
                .y1(function (d) {
                    return y(eval(drawchart));
                }),

            line = d3.svg.line()
                .interpolate('linear')
                .x(function (d) {
                    return x(d.timeStamp) + detailWidth / 2;
                })
                .y(function (d) {
                    return y(eval(drawchart));
                }),

            startData = data.map(function (datum) {
                return {
                    timeStamp: datum.timeStamp,
                    value: 0
                };
            }),

            circleContainer;

        // Compute the minimum and maximum date, and the maximum price.
        x.domain([data[0].timeStamp, data[data.length - 1].timeStamp]);
        // hacky hacky hacky :(
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
            return eval(drawchart);
        }) + 100]);

        svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'lineChart--xAxisTicks')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + detailWidth / 2 + ',' + height + ')')
            .call(xAxisTicks);

        svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'lineChart--xAxis')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + detailWidth / 2 + ',' + ( height + 7 ) + ')')
            .call(xAxis);

        svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'lineChart--yAxisTicks')
            .call(yAxisTicks);

        // Add the line path.
        svg.append('path')
            .datum(startData)
            .attr('class', 'lineChart--areaLine')
            .attr('d', line)
            .transition()
            .duration(DURATION)
            .delay(DURATION / 2)
            .attrTween('d', tween(data, line))
            .each('end', function () {
                drawCircles(data);
            });

        // Add the area path.
        svg.append('path')
            .datum(startData)
            .attr('class', 'lineChart--area')
            .attr('d', area)
            .transition()
            .duration(DURATION)
            .attrTween('d', tween(data, area));

        // Helper functions!!!
        function drawCircle(datum, index) {
            circleContainer.datum(datum)
                .append('circle')
                .attr('class', 'lineChart--circle')
                .attr('r', 0)
                .attr(
                'cx',
                function (d) {
                    return x(d.timeStamp) + detailWidth / 2;
                }
            )
                .attr(
                'cy',
                function (d) {
                    return y(eval(drawchart));
                }
            )
                .on('mouseenter', function (d) {
                    d3.select(this)
                        .attr(
                        'class',
                        'lineChart--circle lineChart--circle__highlighted'
                    )
                        .attr('r', 2.5);

                    d.active = true;

                    showCircleDetail(d);
                })
                .on('mouseout', function (d) {
                    d3.select(this)
                        .attr(
                        'class',
                        'lineChart--circle'
                    )
                        .attr('r', 2.5);

                    if (d.active) {
                        hideCircleDetails();

                        d.active = false;
                    }
                })
                .on('click touch', function (d) {
                    if (d.active) {
                        showCircleDetail(d)
                    } else {
                        hideCircleDetails();
                    }
                })
                .transition()
                .delay(DURATION / 10 * index)
                .attr('r', 2.5);
        }

        function drawCircles(data) {
            circleContainer = svg.append('g');

            data.forEach(function (datum, index) {
                drawCircle(datum, index);
            });
        }

        function hideCircleDetails() {
            circleContainer.selectAll('.lineChart--bubble')
                .remove();
        }

        function showCircleDetail(data) {
            var details = circleContainer.append('g')
                .attr('class', 'lineChart--bubble')
                .attr(
                'transform',
                function () {
                    var result = 'translate(';

                    result += x(data.timeStamp);
                    result += ', ';
                    result += y(eval(dataChart)) - detailHeight - detailMargin;
                    result += ')';

                    return result;
                }
            );

            details.append('path')
                .attr('d', 'm-36.6941,-1c-3.0292,0 -5.4848,1.3422 -5.4848,2.999l0,44.6691c0,1.6562 2.4526,2.999 5.4865,2.999l75.71,0c8.3518,3.7228 0.1055,-0.0614 8.3934,3.8017c8.0794,-3.7725 0.0085,-0.0325 8.2307,-3.8017l75.8633,0c3.03499,0 5.495,-1.3422 5.495,-2.999l0,-44.6691c0,-1.6563 -2.465,-2.999 -5.485,-2.999l-168.209,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l-0.0001,0zm0,0')
                .attr('width', detailWidth)
                .attr('height', detailHeight);

            var text = details.append('text')
                .attr('class', 'lineChart--bubble--text');

            var date = new Date(data.timeStamp);

            var text = details.append('text')
                .attr('class', 'lineChart--bubble--text');
            text.append('tspan')
                .attr('class', 'lineChart--bubble--label')
                .attr('x', detailWidth / 2)
                .attr('y', detailHeight / 3)
                .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
                .text(timeConverter(date));

            text.append('tspan')
                .attr('class', 'lineChart--bubble--value')
                .attr('x', detailWidth / 2)
                .attr('y', detailHeight / 4 * 3)
                .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
                .text(eval(dataChart));

        }

    }

    var data = dataset;
    drawLineChart(elementId, data);

}

//time converter funtion returns the time in human readble manner
function timeConverter(timestamp) {

    var string = String(timestamp);
    var numb = string.indexOf("(");
    var timeUTC = string.substring(0, numb);

    return timeUTC;
}

function tween(b, callback) {
    return function (a) {
        var i = d3.interpolateArray(a, b);

        return function (t) {
            return callback(i(t));
        };
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.10/d3.min.js"></script>

<div class="row title">

        <div class="title-main text-center">
            <h1 id="mainTitle" style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 60px">{{type}} Statistics</h1>
            <h3> {{id}}</h3>
            <input type="hidden" value={{type}} id='chartType'>
            <input type="hidden" value={{id}} id='IdValue'>

        </div>

    </div>

<div class="container-fluid content" style="padding-bottom:40px">
    </br>
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{url "/applications/"}}{{alias}}/" role="button" style="margin-bottom: 24px;">Back</a>
  
    <div class="row">

     <!-- Memory Consumption chart panel-->
        <div class="col-md-6">

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title" style="color:Black">Memory Consumption Average</h3>
                </div>
                
                <div class="panel-body btn-group" >
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-info"  name="MemoryConsumption" id="30Min" onclick="return DurationOnClick(this)">30 mins</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-info" autofocus="true"  name="MemoryConsumption" id="1Hour" onclick="return DurationOnClick(this)">1 hour</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-info" name="MemoryConsumption" id="1Day" onclick="return DurationOnClick(this)">1 day</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-info" name="MemoryConsumption" id="1Week" onclick="return DurationOnClick(this)">1 week</button>a
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-info" name="MemoryConsumption" id="1Month" onclick="return DurationOnClick(this)">1 month</button>
                    <div class="container content" style="width: 600px;">

                        <div class="row text-center" id="chart1">

                         <div id="container1">
                          <svg id="lineChartSVGchart1" class="lineChart--svg">
                            <defs>
                              <linearGradient id="lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
                                <stop class="lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea--top" offset="0%" />
                                <stop class="lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea--bottom" offset="100%" />
                              </linearGradient>
                            </defs>
                          </svg>
                         </div>
                         
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

     <!-- Load Average chart panel-->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title" style="color:Black">Load Average</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body btn-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-info" name="LoadAverage" id="30Min" onclick="return DurationOnClick(this)">30 mins</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-info" autofocus="true" name="LoadAverage" id="1Hour" onclick="return DurationOnClick(this)">1 hour</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-info" name="LoadAverage" id="1Day" onclick="return DurationOnClick(this)">1 day</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-info" name="LoadAverage" id="1Week" onclick="return DurationOnClick(this)">1 week</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-info" name="LoadAverage" id="1Month" onclick="return DurationOnClick(this)">1 month</button>
                    <div class="container content" style="width: 600px;">                        
                        <div class="row text-center" id="chart2">

                         <div id="container2">
                          <svg id="lineChartSVGchart2" class="lineChart--svg">
                            <defs>
                              <linearGradient id="lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
                                <stop class="lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea--top" offset="0%" />
                                <stop class="lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea--bottom" offset="100%" />
                              </linearGradient>
                            </defs>
                          </svg>
                         </div>
                         
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{#if condition}}            
         <!-- In Flight Request Count chart panel-->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title" style="color:Black">In Flight Request Count</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body btn-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-info" name="InFlight" id="30Min" onclick="return DurationOnClick(this)">30 mins</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-info" autofocus="true" name="InFlight" id="1Hour" onclick="return DurationOnClick(this)">1 hour</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-info" name="InFlight" id="1Day" onclick="return DurationOnClick(this)">1 day</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-info" name="InFlight" id="1Week" onclick="return DurationOnClick(this)">1 week</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-info" name="InFlight" id="1Month" onclick="return DurationOnClick(this)">1 month</button>
                        <div class="container content" style="width: 600px;">                            
                         <div class="row text-center" id="chart3">

                        <div id="container3">
                          <svg id="lineChartSVGchart3" class="lineChart--svg">
                            <defs>
                              <linearGradient id="lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
                                <stop class="lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea--top" offset="0%" />
                                <stop class="lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea--bottom" offset="100%" />
                              </linearGradient>
                            </defs>
                          </svg>
                         </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
     {{/if}}
    
    <!-- will trigger on load and pass the default data to the charts-->
    <body onload="bodyOnLoad()">
   
    </body>
```

This is the dataset which I tried to parse,

```
var data = [{"clusterId":"cartridge-group-app.my-tomcat.tomcat.domain","timeStamp":1437417228979,"inFlightRequestCount":22.0},{"clusterId":"cartridge-group-app.my-tomcat.tomcat.domain","timeStamp":1437417288983,"inFlightRequestCount":32.5},{"clusterId":"cartridge-group-app.my-tomcat.tomcat.domain","timeStamp":1437417348980,"inFlightRequestCount":42.5},{"clusterId":"cartridge-group-app.my-tomcat.tomcat.domain","timeStamp":1437417408983,"inFlightRequestCount":52.5},{"clusterId":"cartridge-group-app.my-tomcat.tomcat.domain","timeStamp":1437417468981,"inFlightRequestCount":62.0},{"clusterId":"cartridge-group-app.my-tomcat.tomcat.domain","timeStamp":1437417528982,"inFlightRequestCount":66.66666666666667},{"clusterId":"cartridge-group-app.my-tomcat.tomcat.domain","timeStamp":1437417588983,"inFlightRequestCount":48.75},{"clusterId":"cartridge-group-app.my-tomcat.tomcat.domain","timeStamp":1437417648983,"inFlightRequestCount":41.25},{"clusterId":"cartridge-group-app.my-tomcat.tomcat.domain","timeStamp":1437417708980,"inFlightRequestCount":55.0},{"clusterId":"cartridge-group-app.my-tomcat.tomcat.domain","timeStamp":1437417768983,"inFlightRequestCount":90.0},{"clusterId":"cartridge-group-app.my-tomcat.tomcat.domain","timeStamp":1437417828981,"inFlightRequestCount":90.0}];
```

I don't know why it gives such output. Can anyone please help me to figure this out?

Comment: The error is not from any of the code you posted. You need to post the code that is throwing.

Comment: That isn't how the parsing is meant to be used. Check the https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting

Comment: Your time format specifier is wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645216/d3-time-scale-x-axis-with-unix-timestamp

Comment: @LarsKotthoff i tried ur way but i got this error for that.

 Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M49,NaNL99.2031793227356,NaNL149.40050199832666,NaNL199.60284465718448,NaNL249.80100399665335,NaNL300.00167332775555,NaNL350.2023426588578,NaNL400.4021753260822,NaNL450.59949800167334,NaNL500.8018406605312,NaNL551,NaN"

my code snipest :

data.forEach(function(data) { data.timeStamp = new Date(data.timeStamp); });

Comment: @d7k Did you look at the answer to the question I've linked to?

Comment: yes from that i took this below code snippets.

Comment: @d7k Well you took the code that doesn't work. As explained in the answer, you need to multiply the timestamp by 1000 to make it valid input for Javascript's `Date()`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff in my case i have 13 digits for the timestamp. so i guess it doesn't need to multiply it by 1000. even though i use with 1438691812431(current what i have with me) this timestamp it gives the same error.

Comment: @d7k Ah yes, you're right. So the error must be coming from somewhere else.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff can u help with to find it. I was like stuck about 4 days in this problem.

Comment: @d7k I can't tell you where the error is without seeing the code.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Hi lars i have attached the whole code in the question. Can you see why that error comes?

Comment: @d7k Which line is causing the error?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff i debugged the code. The error comes after this line part executed. // Add the line path.
        svg.append('path')
            .datum(startData)
            .attr('class', 'lineChart--areaLine')
            .attr('d', line)
            .transition()
            .duration(DURATION)
            .delay(DURATION / 2)
            .attrTween('d', tween(data, line))
            .each('end', function () {
                drawCircles(data);
            });
It error says it comes from the "d3.v3.min.js:22" line number 22 in the d3 js file.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff i couldnot get why it doesn't get the svg path correctly. i have mentioned before that what i receive (the d value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d3.time.format( '%Y-%m-%d' ).parse
```

expects a string in the annotated format and returns the corresponding Date object.

**EDIT for clarification**

It seems that i misunderstood your intention.

If you want to FORMAT your timestamp from 1437417228979 into something readable like "2015-07-20 20:33" you use

```
var format = d3.time.format( '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' );
for (i = 0; i < data.length;i++) {
    data[i].timeStamp = format (new Date(data[i].timeStamp)); 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/94ao83n7/1/

If you want to PARSE your timestamp into an actual javascript Date object  you can simply put the timestamp into the constructor of the Date object

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length;i++) {
    data[i].timeStamp = new Date(data[i].timeStamp); 
}
```

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting

Comment: This won't work because you're 1) not actually calling the `.parse()` method of the time formatter, 2) using a `Date` object instead of a string (as you point out yourself) and 3) assume that the format will be year-month-day, which it isn't if you coerce a `Date` object to a string.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff isn't https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#_format stating that you ca give a Date object to d3.time.format( '%Y-%m-%d' ) and it will return the corresponding string ?
My fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/94ao83n7/ works fine for me, besides the fact that the timestamps do not differentiate in year,month day and thus the formatting returns the same string for all of them.

Comment: The code in your fiddle is different to what you posted here (in particular the format string). You're not actually parsing the dates (as is OP's intention from the code snippet in the question), but formatting them.

Comment: I only changed the format string to be able to actually see a difference between the time stamps as the format chosen by the OP would output the same for every entry.
Maybe i misunderstood the question, i thought the intention was to format 1437417228979 into "2015-07-20" or  "2015-07-20 20:33"(in my fiddle). If the intention was to get a javascript Date object from his time stamps, he could have simply used the Date constructor. Will edit my answer to clarify that.

Comment: It's my impression that OP is trying to parse and not format.