# Epoch Time conversion with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This seems like a trivial question, but I am getting a strange error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: t.slice is not a function"

when trying to pass a unix timestamp to my code.

```
var myDate = new Date(1075611600000);
  var format = d3.time.format("%Y").parse; //Trying to return the year.
  console.log(format(myDate)); //error noted above
  console.log(myDate); //Sun Feb 01 2004 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

Anyone see the obvious mistake I am making? Thanks in advance. I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645216/d3-time-scale-x-axis-with-unix-timestamp) example and I do not see what I am doing wrong. I am trying to return only the year.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`format` function expects a string and you pass in a `Date` object which does not have `slice` function.

I believe this is what you want to achieve:

```
var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");
console.log(format(new Date(1075611600000))); // returns a string
```

[[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/7137/)]

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a `Date` to your `parse` method, [where you should pass it a `string`.](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#parse)

If you want to get a `string` out of a `Date`, [don't use `.parse()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#_format).

---

PS: you're using the minified d3, so `Uncaught TypeError: t.slice is not a function` stands for :

```
Uncaught TypeError: string.slice is not a function

d3_time_parseFullYear @ d3.js:2760
d3_time_parse @ d3.js:2563
format.parse @ d3.js:2538
```